# Circular referencing resources in ARM template with Web App and SQL Database

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create one basic real world ARM template that contains both SQL Database and a Web App that hosts a REST API. The SQL database creation needs to add the inbound ip address of the REST API to add to the database firewall rules. The REST API creation needs to add the SQL database connection string. What is the simplest and recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [ARM template](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-complex-application-predictably.md) to create a WebApp with SQL database .

For more information please refer the below links:

. [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers?tabs=bicep)

. [Azure Quickstart template for webapp & sql](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/web-app-sql-database)

. [Deploying a web app and an Azure SQL database with ARM template without | ARTICLE](https://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/deploying-a-web-app-and-an-azure-sql-database-with-arm-template-without-providing-any-password).